# Electrum private key sweep

Tags: private-key, electrum, private-key-import

I'm trying to sweep private keys in Electrum but it asks to input: p2pkh:, p2wpkh: or p2wpkh-p2sh before the keys based on the address. I only have the keys but no address, how can I proceed with this safely?

Comment: What about using the same command three times on three sweeps?

Answer (score 1):

To sweep private keys in Electrum, you need the associated addresses. **Without the addresses, it's not possible to determine the correct format** (p2pkh, p2wpkh, or p2wpkh-p2sh) for the private keys.

You can try using a [tool](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) to generate the addresses from the private keys, but this process should be done with caution as it involves exposing your private keys to a third-party website.

**It's recommended to use a secure and offline environment to generate addresses from private keys.**